# Load Balancer Setting Based on ip and or header

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, url-routing, load-balancing

Is it possible to configure a load balancer URL mapping based on the IP  it is sent from and header? Anything from Google Cloud or AWS?

I know can be done via an envoy proxy but is there a google cloud/aws based solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about GCP, but yes you can do it using an [AWS ALB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html).

There is a config called `target groups`. You can create rules based on `header`, `path`, `IP`, `query string` and etc. Take a look on the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html) about target groups.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Looks promising, Google Cloud Load balancers only do this based on headers. Looking for a Google Cloud solution but this is helpful if there is no other option might migrate to AWS.